# How to make a datetime object from user input?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, user-input

I am trying to make an alarm clock. How to make a datetime object from user-input, where the user-input is hours, minutes, and secs seperately. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

# user-input: at 2:30
hr = "2"
m = "30"
s = "0"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Yes, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
def GetDate():
    isValid=False
    while not isValid:
        userIn = input("Type Date dd/mm/yy: ")
        try: # strptime throws an exception if the input doesn't match the pattern
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(userIn, "%d/%m/%y")
            isValid=True
        except:
            print("Invalid")
    return d

#test the function
print(GetDate())
```